# Convert Block Number Hash to Readable Block Number?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, parity, json-rpc, dapps

When i use this command :

```
curl --data '{"method":"eth_getBlockByNumber","params":["latest", true],"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST localhost:8544
```

Then I am getting this response :

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":{"author":"0x2a65aca4d5fc5b5c859090a6c34d164135398226","difficulty":"0x23796dec9350","extraData":"0xd783010404844765746887676f312e362e32856c696e7578","gasLimit":"0x47e7c4","gasUsed":"0x1e8d3","hash":"0x8918e1c221fca4bbd2686e2b991eedb55e5e07a56867b6444d6064db7a1f2132","logsBloom":"0x00000010000000020000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000040000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000","miner":"0x2a65aca4d5fc5b5c859090a6c34d164135398226","mixHash":"0xd7f23f011e484617fda230b8a123050e9ddb68db0e2107b6e92c354d8d030d36","nonce":"0x7cb02500056bd498","number":"0x178def","parentHash":"0x309ccfe954d223a41165d5f8e79084b8cd8949602d30d5960d837d9fd2c7ab97","receiptsRoot":"0xbdfe515f906a594396675ea4417f2de701e147f6263525fcd2a8e63e955a8d70","sealFields":["0xa0d7f23f011e484617fda230b8a123050e9ddb68db0e2107b6e92c354d8d030d36","0x887cb02500056bd498"],"sha3Uncles":"0x1dcc4de8dec75d7aab85b567b6ccd41ad312451b948a7413f0a142fd40d49347","size":"0x398","stateRoot":"0x3eca3ea525993d54b46b18a3f65752ee4d18c54d2c4c8e413864aa5b14867327","timestamp":"0x573d35cd","totalDifficulty":"0x11c4f37beb4be0c5c","transactions":[{"blockHash":"0x8918e1c221fca4bbd2686e2b991eedb55e5e07a56867b6444d6064db7a1f2132","blockNumber":"0x178def","chainId":null,"condition":null,"creates":null,"from":"0xea674fdde714fd979de3edf0f56aa9716b898ec8","gas":"0x15f90","gasPrice":"0x4a817c800","hash":"0xf21a395a97066b135278eb589d6e0472fd9d1e592aaada32ad61dc4e34fa7e29","input":"0x","nonce":"0x191a1","publicKey":"0x5d8af02c52b1fb40e45d6e04ae2351d443d1f7327e9b6dbb5ae1d918414899c625690c4c236889e23d9705f9db88876542b959d947a3497a30d0d922ee30015f","r":"0xc34afbc29e616513a28503097652f7ae62b9dbffb9eecc592dd625a0bf34c940","raw":"0xf870830191a18504a817c80083015f909451c7d68f3a4089e6e6d142dee0569b6770e6e335880de326b2f64b16b0801ba0c34afbc29e616513a28503097652f7ae62b9dbffb9eecc592dd625a0bf34c940a018717fbbeeda52a6adb8f2a059e05b72fcff03433e86aeca453eee06ef70cdc6","s":"0x18717fbbeeda52a6adb8f2a059e05b72fcff03433e86aeca453eee06ef70cdc6","standardV":"0x0","to":"0x51c7d68f3a4089e6e6d142dee0569b6770e6e335","transactionIndex":"0x0","v":"0x1b","value":"0xde326b2f64b16b0"},{"blockHash":"0x8918e1c221fca4bbd2686e2b991eedb55e5e07a56867b6444d6064db7a1f2132","blockNumber":"0x178def","chainId":null,"condition":null,"creates":null,"from":"0x4bc6c54e71ea68d069c895983812d426dc296b77","gas":"0x15f90","gasPrice":"0x4a817c800","hash":"0xcceefc4aaab15712582d5c96e974dd05e5e61bb7c5f5a4bdf5d101ecfa01dc8e","input":"0x","nonce":"0x8","publicKey":"0x4fcb530d5d1140522eee9c3f9263c5bc5aef49b448b7b1aa6cade7706d6d3bb465d732db660caab962f49ce74794bb67dd0510e24c94de0b45832f545733cc4d","r":"0xc321ec233a88e8cbf08c905e4de6fe729f3913fab9f0b36477f609adda5a69bb","raw":"0xf86d088504a817c80083015f909452929b839b37738439337c5b6a107418f6cb8c3588896909229be8a800801ba0c321ec233a88e8cbf08c905e4de6fe729f3913fab9f0b36477f609adda5a69bba02e76bf3d6b8c210968876d6ec7132f7103915d66e9f1ee481126f030227d59d0","s":"0x2e76bf3d6b8c210968876d6ec7132f7103915d66e9f1ee481126f030227d59d0","standardV":"0x0","to":"0x52929b839b37738439337c5b6a107418f6cb8c35","transactionIndex":"0x1","v":"0x1b","value":"0x896909229be8a800"},{"blockHash":"0x8918e1c221fca4bbd2686e2b991eedb55e5e07a56867b6444d6064db7a1f2132","blockNumber":"0x178def","chainId":null,"condition":null,"creates":null,"from":"0xfbb1b73c4f0bda4f67dca266ce6ef42f520fbb98","gas":"0x38eb3","gasPrice":"0x4a817c800","hash":"0x93c27acf3b0bca776975c674eea2be0e4dd103964dc62741de6848f756d95655","input":"0xbaac5300000000000000000000000000f8357a814f15517494d3bac7c93cd405be5a6c06","nonce":"0x4ca3","publicKey":"0x8178af6e1ae9a747de289f2106a85875288b24a2c6bdb1f069cad506409abdd4f1bd1ac05507615c852a9a74cf3013f7b13b9e0f03870011993e575a357a308d","r":"0x55802fbddf75a40105b04ba7915aaf01479c3637b102c38d70682ccda8133f66","raw":"0xf893824ca38504a817c80083038eb394bb9bc244d798123fde783fcc1c72d3bb8c189413888aa20afbc9ce7000a4baac5300000000000000000000000000f8357a814f15517494d3bac7c93cd405be5a6c061ba055802fbddf75a40105b04ba7915aaf01479c3637b102c38d70682ccda8133f66a00c632501b44e702f530f6a4ac6bfc9c3e74b691e5861ad6372c69909eb5ed948","s":"0xc632501b44e702f530f6a4ac6bfc9c3e74b691e5861ad6372c69909eb5ed948","standardV":"0x0","to":"0xbb9bc244d798123fde783fcc1c72d3bb8c189413","transactionIndex":"0x2","v":"0x1b","value":"0x8aa20afbc9ce7000"}],"transactionsRoot":"0x5528494eb8fd3038468c30050e85ef7cca4603c75ad5a3f222630eb92585eb73","uncles":[]},"id":1}
```

In the above response the block number is : `0x178def` . How to convert this block number to readable block number, like example block number 545 ?

Answer (score 1):

On a Linux command line, without using some hideous grep/regex? :-)

Here's a Python2 method (using Infura as the backend):

```
$ curl -s -X POST --data '{"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0", "method":"eth_getBlockByNumber","params":["latest", true]}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://mainnet.infura.io/<my_infura_key> | python -c "import sys, json; print(int(json.load(sys.stdin)['result']['number'], 0))"
5065179
```

So the important part:

```
<curl_command> | python -c "import sys, json; print(int(json.load(sys.stdin)['result']['number'], 0))"
```

This pipes the output of your `curl` command to a Python command, which parses the JSON, reads the correct field, and converts from a hex string into an integer.

I also passed `-s` to `curl` to run in silent mode.

You could also pipe the output of the curl command to the [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) tool, and do something similar.

Also note that you could just use the [`eth_blockNumber`](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_blocknumber) method, which returns a more simple JSON response.

Comment: Thanks but i am getting this error in python :  `File "<string>", line 1, in <module>` , is this command correct ? : `curl --data '{"method":"eth_getBlockByNumber","params":["latest", true],"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST localhost:8544 | \python -c "import sys, json; print(int(json.loads(sys.stdin)['result']['number'], 0))"` . Also grep/regex way will also work since i want to run this code inside shell script.

Comment: Okay - I was testing with a JSON file, not a stream. I've updated my answer to actually work :-)